# How to resize default NerdTree width?

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I don't know what changed recently but my NerdTree keeps opening up super wide and pushing my existing window to the right. Here's a picture:

Before opening NerdTree:

[image]

After:

[image]

I tried adding this line to my vimrc file: `let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 1`
 but when I exit out of VIM and open it again nothing changes.

Comment: Are you sure that you have `let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 1` in your `.vimrc`? This works perfectly fine for me, and is the correct answer. Perhaps you have a different line that sets it to a new value later? Maybe try putting that line at the very end of the `.vimrc`?

Comment: Yeh I'm sure. And I put it at the end too

Comment: I just ran `PlugUpdate` and it magically fixed itself, now `let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 1` works